# Combining BibTeX entry with multiple parts?

Tags: bibtex, natbib, multiple-citations

I am trying to figure out how to cite this with bibtex. I originally had two separate entries for each 'part', but I want to combine them like in the image. What entry fields can I use to write both titles and both issue months and page numbers? Thank you.

[image: Diamond, Peter A., and James Mirrlees. 1971. "Optimal Taxation and Public Production." Pt. I: "Production Efficiency." Pt.II: "Tax Rules." American Economic Review 61 (March): 8-27; 61 (June): 261-278]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I decided to just do it manually:

```
@article{tag,
  author = "authors",
  year = "year",
  title = "title",
  volume = "Pt. I ``title.'' Pt. II ``title.'' \textit{American Economic Review} 61
  (March): 8-27; 61 (June): 261-278."}
```

I used "volume instead of "note" because "note" left a period right before the section after the quotation marks: "Title.". Pt. I ect.